# Accounting for minimum distance between points when conducting point pattern analyses in spatstat

Tags: spatstat

I've noticed an issue when performing exploratory analyses of my point pattern. When plotting a G function in spatstat, I've noticed G values remain near zero up to an r of around 5 micron [see below for one example]. I believe this is probably due to the fact that I'm using the centroids of non-overlapping objects as my point pattern. The average diameter of the real objects is somewhere around 5 microns, which is consistent with this strong repulsion-like finding when comparing the G values of my point patterns to that of CSR at distances <5 um. Is there a way to correct for this? E.g., by modeling and performing analysis on the objects as areas or polygons instead of single coordinate points or by using a point process model other than homogenous poission process as a comparator?

I am a beginner user of spatstat and R.

[image: Example G function plot]